# cannot connect to my winsock server from another computer using my IP address

Tags: c++, winsock

i am working on a chat.

i can start my server and client on the same computer using the 127.0.0.1 ip address and can talk fine, but if I try using my own IP address in the client to connect to the server, it does not connect. If someone else also tries to do it, it doesn't work

i have portforwarded in my router like this:

```
external host: my ip
internal host: my internal ip i got with ipconfig (192.168.1.4)
internal port: 54444
external port: 54444
```

even then, I think I should still be able to connect to my IP address without a portforward since the server is hosted on 127.0.0.1/localhost, right?

this is my client code:

```
WSADATA wsa;
    if (!WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa))
    {
        printf("started server\n");
        SOCKET listen_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (listen_sock)
        {
            printf("created listen socket\n");

            sockaddr_in addr;
            addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            inet_pton(AF_INET, "92.83.235.216", &addr.sin_addr);
            addr.sin_port = htons(54444);

            if (!connect(listen_sock, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&addr), sizeof(addr)))
            {
                printf("connected to server\n");

                char buffer[2048];
                char input[2048];

                for(;;)
                {
                    printf("message: ");
                    scanf_s("%s", input);

                    if (send(listen_sock, input, strlen(input) + 1, 0))
                    {
                        printf("\nsent message \"%s\"", input);
                    }

                    memset(input, 0, sizeof(input));
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    WSACleanup();
```

it stops after it shows "creating listen socket", right at the connect() call

Any ideas?

EDIT: server code is very jumbled because of me making it into a class to make it easier to use + adding a thread to handle multiple connections, but like I said it does work internall

only thing different in the server code besides the listen and accept calls is these rules i added:

```
char opt_val = 1;
setsockopt(this->m_listen_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt_val, sizeof(opt_val));
setsockopt(this->m_listen_sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &opt_val, sizeof(opt_val));
```

Comment: If your server is listening on 127.0.0.1 then you will only be able to connect to it from the same computer.  You need to listen on the public IP address to receive connections from other computers.

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried that too. What I meant to say is that I also tried just listening on my localhost

Comment: Unclear: `localhost` is `127.0.0.1` which cannot be used if you want to connect from another machine.  If you were using another address then check the local firewall.

Comment: my firewall is turned off. i have tried my ip address that i got off google for my server. really weird that it doesn't work

Comment: @Bozz You didn't show your server code. But since you have a router involved, and you claim that its port forwarding is setup correctly, then a possibility is that your ISP is simply blocking inbound connections from reaching your router. Some ISPs don't like customers hosting servers without paying extra for that privilege. Talk to your ISP to see if that is the case.

Comment: Your question is incomplete without server code, and also without the actual error. You are printing the error if `connect()` fails : in fact you're printing it even if it doesn't fail, which doesn't make much sense. Anyway why haven't you posted it here? And why aren't you closing the client socket? And your server should bind to INADDR_ANY

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like your `SYN` packets are being dropped (`SYN`... no `SYN/ACK` or `RST`).  You can use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see what is happening with the actual tcp connection (filter on port).

You might want to eliminate the server as a source of error by listening on `localhost` and connecting that way.  You can verify it is listening on the correct address and port using `netstat`.

Otherwise, it would help if you posted your server code.